# GWT Feedback Tab

Tags: gwt

Is there a GWT implementation of a Feedback Widget?

Comment: The value you get out of this site will increase if you ask questions more specific than this one and leave feedback for the answers you got to your earlier questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such widget that comes with GWT, but you can easily create one.  The GWT Showcase shows many of the widgets that are available:

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html

However, as stated, you should be able to create a feedback widget fairly easily, by creating a UiBinder class (designed however you like), and creating a GWT RPC service to send everything over the wire.  You can then process the provided feedback however you like in the service's server-side implementation (email it, store it in the datastore, etc).